# Appcelerator Platform support error in adhoc build of Titanium mobile

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

A support error occurs when performing a build.

```
$ ti build -T dist-adhoc
```

```
This application cannot be built with the Titanium open source SDK because it is an 
Appcelerator Platform registered application. Please use the Appcelerator Platform CLI 
tools or Appcelerator Studio to build this application
```

No login is available.

```
$ appc login
```

```
Support for the Appcelerator CLI has ceased from March 1st 2022. 
Please migrate to the OSS Titanium and Alloy tooling for Titanium purposes or the Axway CLI for Axway purposes
```

I have done the build with the information on this website, is there anything I am missing?

https://titaniumsdk.com/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_Guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference/#build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the "transfer from Appc -> ti" part
https://titaniumsdk.com/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_How-tos/Transfer_your_app_from_appc_CLI_to_ti_CLI/

In your case it should just be the GUID. Go to  https://www.guidgenerator.com and create a new one and use that.

After that you should be ready to build again

Comment: Thank you.
Changing the guid solved the problem.

https://community.axway.com/s/question/0D57S00000BLcQXSA1/how-to-build-for-production-now-that-appcelerator-offering-has-been-discontinued

Comment: there are multiple places with the infos. I even have it in my tutorial list https://fromzerotoapp.com/transfer-your-app-from-appc-cli-to-ti-cli/ because it was asked a lot last year when they've switched off the support